# generate web.config at run time - sitecore

Tags: runtime, sitecore, configuration-files, sitecore7.2, web.config-transform

I integrated active directory with sitecore and it works perfect, now i am trying to write patches for the config changes. Sections  `<membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1"> and <roleManager defaultProvider="sitecore" enabled="true">` are changed for connection setting to AD. When i try to write config patch for this section, this section is not built at run time. But the domains section works, i mean the patch i created for this section works and writes to web.config at runtime. I observed a difference here Domains section is under `<Sitecore>,  <membership> and <roleManager >` are in `<system.web>` section. Is this the reason that these are not included in web.config? can we write patches for those sections only under `<sitecore>?`

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can only patch elements within the /configuration/sitecore element.

Refer this post:
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

I think you have to use config transforms as mentioned by leandro.

Answer (score 0):

I assumming you are using Visual Studio ¿? You must specify in what are you working.

If so, you need create a transform file for the build configuration that you need, for example, one config for every environment or publish type.

Try a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am working on sitecore project..I am using Visual Studio 2013..i am talking about the Include of custom config patches at runtime..sitecore does build the web.config at runtime which are created in Include folder of the project..

Comment: it's I'm talking about. Try it